# Tesseract Project: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "png_set_longjmp_fn" refrenced by "liblept.so"

Tags: android, cygwin, tesseract, dlopen, tess-two

I'm trying to make an app that use tess-two library and is suppose to give me back the string format of a word picture.

this is my process for importing tess-two and I'm using cygwin for it:

**PART1: CYGWIN:**

```
export TESSERACT_PATH=${PWD}/external/tesseract-3.04
export  LEPTONICA_PATH=${PWD}/external/leptonica-1.72
export LIBJPEG_PATH=${PWD}/external/libjpeg
export ANDROID_HOME="/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Android/android-sdk"
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH

android.bat update project --target 1 --path .
```

**PART2: cmd:**

```
cd "<tess-two directory>"
C:\...\android-ndk-r10e\ndk-build.cmd
```

Then I Imported tess-two and when I run my app, booom, this error appear, I will be so thankfull if anyone help me with this error.

**IMPORTANT**  I don't know that my cygwin code has worked correctly or not and the problem is from there.

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you were following the old build instruction, probably from [here](http://kurup87.blogspot.in/2012/03/android-ocr-tutorial-image-to-text.html). The export process for TESSERACT_PATH,LEPTONICA_PATH,and LIBJPEG_PATH seems to be not necessary anymore. Besides, the tess-two project is now using LIBPNG so no need for LIBJPEG.

And the error log you described in your title is caused by a bug which is fixed 5 days ago. I recommend you to download the latest version of tess-two and build it again and don't forget to use "android update project --path ." and  "ant release" after "ndk-build".